# Accessing the gmail labels api in android

Tags: android, gmail

I've got an app in the play store which reads the gmail labels (based on the sample app provided on the google blog)

It works fine for most people, but for some they get the following error from the app:

```
 "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.gm.provider.PublicContentProvider uri content://com.google.android.gm/test@example.com/labels from pid=29069, uid=10087 requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_CONTENT_PROVIDER, or grantUriPermission()"
```

The code I'm using is:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(GmailContract.Labels.getLabelsUri(accountName),null, null, null, null);
```

And my manifest file has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_CONTENT_PROVIDER" />
```

Therefore I've no idea why some people they get this error. It's not just a handful of people, there's over 100 people that have reported this (but thousands that haven't)

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with java. But, [Sms Backup Plus](https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus) application includes a similar feature. Be useful to consider.

Comment: Thanks, looking at that I think it handles it totally differently as it's hooking up to the internet and using gmail on there to write out the data whereas I'm using the labels API directly on the phone.

Comment: Ohh, Sorry @Andrew, I misunderstand.

Comment: no worries I'd forgotten sms backup plus was opensource and it's always handy to have references to other apps to look at!